# how to style input on tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am writing to Tinymce extension, the purpose of extension is to allow the user make comments on the text.
When I click the comment button opens me input. I'm trying to change the style has a width and higher, I could but it does not look good.
Attaching code and picture.

plugin js

> ```
> tinymce.PluginManager.add('comments', function(editor/*, url*/) {
>   // Add a button that opens a window
>   editor.addButton('comments', {
>     title: 'comment',
>     //text: 'My button',
>     //icon: false,
>     image: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/comment-outline-silence-128.png",
>     onclick: function() {
>       // Open window
>       editor.windowManager.open({
>         title: 'write comment ',
>         body: [
>           {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Post a Comment', value: "hello", height: 40,
> width: 30}
>         ],
>         width: 800,
>         height: 400,
>         onsubmit: function(e) {
>           // Insert content when the window form is submitted
>           let div= document.createElement("span");
>           div.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";
>           div.innerHTML=editor.selection.getContent();
>           let span= document.createElement("span");
>           div.appendChild(span);
>           span.innerHTML = e.data.title;
>           span.classList.add ("comment");
>           editor.insertContent(div.outerHTML);
>         }
>       });
>     }
>   });
> ```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea', plugins: 'comments', toolbar: 'comments', content_css : '/js/tinymce/plugins/comments/styleComments.css' });</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

It does not look good, how can I design it in general in addition to height and width.

Thank you all

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your body try defining the field this way:

```
{
    type: 'container',
    label  : 'fit',
    layout: 'fit',
    minWidth: 160,
    minHeight: 160,
    items: [{
        type: 'textbox',
        label: 'textbox',
        value: 'Fit will take all the space available.'
    }]
}
```

... or this way...

```
{
    type   : 'textbox',
    name   : 'textbox multiline',
    label  : 'textbox multiline',
    multiline : true,
    value  : 'default value\non another line'
}
```